# What happens when a character puts on a "Ring of Water Walking" while already underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, underwater

Got into an interesting conversation with a friend about this, and neither of us were quite sure as to what the actual effect of the ring would have on someone if they were already underwater.

Comment: Related: [Can someone who's wearing a Ring of Water Walking be pulled underwater?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122596/can-someone-whos-wearing-a-ring-of-water-walking-be-pulled-underwater) and [Can I voluntarily go underwater if I have Water Walk cast on me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120659/can-i-voluntarily-go-underwater-if-i-have-water-walk-cast-on-me)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Nothing, unless you choose to swim to the surface.

The description of the [Ring of Water Walking](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-water-walking) states:

> While wearing this ring, you can stand on and move across any liquid surface as if it were solid ground.

It simply gives you the ability to walk on the surface of water as if it were solid ground. It doesn't force you to do anything, and doesn't force anything to happen to you. Since you're underwater, there's no liquid surface to walk on from your present position.

Of course, you can swim to the surface of the water. From that point, you would be able to stand on and move on the surface of the water as if it were solid ground.

Comment: "Since you're underwater, there's no liquid surface to walk on from your present position." - I wonder if you could do anything interesting with bubbles or some other way of generating a surface.

Comment: Good point. Make a bubble large enough and you could technically stand on the lower surface while being *inside* the bubble. Quite an innovative way to, say, escape an underwater prison.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you could walk up to the surface like walking on stairs.  As far as being pulled under I think the spirit of the magic is to keep you on top of the water so you should have some advantages against getting pulled or just cant be.