# Can you take fall damage falling into water under the effects of the Water Walk spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, falling

The [*water walk*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/water-walk) spell states that it "grants the ability to move across any liquid surface [...] as if it were harmless solid ground".

If you fall off a cliff with *water walk* active on you and the water below you is treated as solid ground, will you take normal fall damage? Or can you suspend the spell, causing the water to soften the fall as usual?

Comment: @MarkTO Remember also that comments aren’t for debate. To resolve that, either just leave it be, or promote it to a full question. Either course of action keeps debate out of the comments.

Comment: @DaleM No answering in comments. At worst, it starts arguments that require moderator intervention.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120659/can-i-voluntarily-go-underwater-if-i-have-water-walk-cast-on-me) from last year covers your question I feel.

The quick of it is that the spell gives you the ***ability*** to move over water as if it was solid ground, but it’s not *forced* on you. You can choose not to use the ability and treat it as normal water for the purposes of crossing over it.

The bouyance part of that spell does say:

> **If you target a creature submerged in a liquid**, the spell carries the target to the surface of the liquid at a rate of 60 feet per round.

Emphasis mine.

So this presents two scenarios:

- Water Walk cast on you outside of water, you do **not** get the buoyancy benefit/detriment for the duration of the spell.
- Water Walk cast on you while submerged, you **do** get the buoyancy benefit/detriment for the duration of the spell.

Comment: It may also be worth addressing whether "falling into water" fits the definition of "moving across any liquid surface". I would say that it probably doesn't.

Comment: According to a comment from that thread, one's buoyancy might not be affected at all unless the spell was cast on them *while they were already submerged:* "This applies only when you target a creature submerged in a liquid, i.e. at the time of casting. The creature cannot 'opt out' of it, though. The spell explicitly forces it up at the stated rate."

Comment: This is interesting because deep enough underwater, or in the Plane of Water, it turns Water Walk into the old 3.5 Epic spell 'Nail to the Sky'

Comment: I made some edits. Note that we aren’t a discussion forum and our pages aren’t “threads”; we use formatting rather than SHOUTING for emphasis; we have a help guide on how formatting works for complex items like lists ([formatting guide](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)); edit notes and marks shouldn’t be noted in the post since we have a robust edit history feature ([FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454/321)).

Comment: The question asks about whether you take fall damage when falling onto liquid/water under the effect of *water walk* spell. Can you include an explicit line to answer this question? **Yes, it does prevent/No, it does not prevent**

Comment: @MarkTO Heh, I like that. But the spell doesn't say 'up' but 'to the surface', and the plane of water either lacks a surface or has several all over the place, in the form of air pockets. At least I think so.